# WebView (webkit) "Look Up In Dictionary" UI Bug - Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

I've found a bug with WebView that is easy to recreate but hard to solve and am looking for suggestions and preferably answers.

The bug is when you use Apple's built in dictionary "look up" command by any means, contextual menu, multi touch gesture (3 finger double tap), or the standard global hot key "cmd ctrl d".  After invoking the dictionary look up command, a popover will appear with the definition of the word you highlighted.  However, text on the page sometimes gets blurred and forms/fields no longer respond properly to input events like mouseDown.

Like I said earlier, it is pretty easy to duplicate.  I've uploaded a sample project to GitHub.

https://github.com/ChimpStudios/WebView-DictionaryBug

Safari doesn't have this bug, so somehow Apple fixed it, but it still exists in the WebView object.

Comment: I was able to repro this on my 10.7 machine but not my 10.6 machine.  Nice bug find!  You should get this onto Apple's [Radar](http://bugreporter.apple.com) bug reporting system.  I wonder if there's a way to run this with any downloadable frameworks from www.webkit.org?

Comment: I opened a bug with Apple.  #10318203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling -[WebPreferences setPreferencesIdentifier:] so that your WebView gets its own WebPreferences copy appears to be an effective workaround.

Comment: It worked!  This bug has been giving me trouble for quite a while now so I'm happy to have it fixed.